# Is there any way to disable FitNesse page caching?

Tags: fitnesse

We are trying to use multiple instances of FitNesse with the same backing store of pages. The intention is that we use command-line variable declarations to set environment-specific variables differently, so that we can run the same test suites against different environments.

This all works great, except that we find that FitNesse seems to cache pages in memory, specifically the following use case doesn't work for us:

1. Go to FitNesse instance 1 and delete or rename a page.
2. Go to FitNesse instance 2 - observe that page (if it had been previously accessed) still appears to be there.
3. Restart FitNesse instance 2 - page is gone (as expected).

We'd gladly pay the (I assume small) hit to performance of page rendering if we could disable this caching behavior.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of recent changes to FitNesse that are in the edge, but not in the release, that might improve the behavior for you.  I know that one feature directly related to the removing of CachingPage. https://cleancoder.ci.cloudbees.com/job/fitnesse/lastStableBuild/

I haven't tried this particular scenario, so I can't guarantee it resolves it. I also don't usually recommend running two instances out of the same folder structure. When I have done so, the second instance really only existed to view results of tests.

Comment: Thanks Dan, we're on the latest release (May 30, 2013) already, so edge wouldn't be too far away from us. Not related to the question directly, but any suggestions why running 2 instances in the way I've described is not recommended? It seems to work well for our  use case. Thanks~

Comment: Well, partly because of the problems you are having here.  The caching would mean that deletes would cause issues.  Additionally, I'm thinking that you can run into a case where the right hand doesn't know what the left is doing.  Why are you running two out of the same?

Comment: The motivation is basically to run the same test suites against multiple environments - we couldn't find a good way to do this through page includes or `!see` directives, but supplying the appropriate variables on the command line seems to be a reasonable and straightforward solution. Typically it's a single QA engineer working on the test suite as a whole, but agree with your concern in general terms! Anyway, this is getting a little off-topic of the original question, thanks for your answer and advice.

Comment: Ah, you need to use http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SymbolicLinks.  You can then have the same tests defined in one place, but then link them in as children of configuration pages.  Then run them from each config page with different variable definitions.

Comment: thanks again for the pointer, we'll take a look and see if it's a better fit for us.